# How can we join two columns of a numpy array into a single column, separating the values by a space?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of string data, and I am currently extracting a subset of it with `data_subset = original_data[:, [1, 3, 8]]`.  However, I want one of the columns in my data subset to be two columns of my original data combined, joined with a space.

An example of the combination I'm thinking of would be the following.  I have 2 columns representing first and last names.  As example example data, a row would have `John` in column 3 and `Smith` in column 4, but in my new data I want a single column `John Smith`.  Is there a nice numpy function to perform such a join?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using the `pandas` library instead of `numpy` here -- using `numpy` arrays for strings is usually more trouble than it's worth.  OTOH, what you want is very straightforward in `pandas`:

```
>>> from pandas import DataFrame
>>> df = DataFrame({"first": ["John", "Jane"], "last": ["Smith", "Jones"]})
>>> df
  first   last
0  John  Smith
1  Jane  Jones
>>> df["first"] + " " + df["last"]
0    John Smith
1    Jane Jones
```

If you absolutely want to use `numpy`, though, you can do what you want if you change the `dtype` to `object`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([["John", "Smith"], ["Jane", "Jones"]])
>>> a = a.astype(object)
>>> a[:,0] += " " + a[:,1]
>>> a = a[:,:1]
>>> a
array([[John Smith],
       [Jane Jones]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard Python to do the joining, something like this should work :

```
data_subset = original_data[:, [1, 3]]
data_subset[:, 1] += " " + original_data[:, 8]
```

Comment: Are you sure?  This returns an error for me. TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'numpy.ndarray' objects